# github api get number of pull requests

Tags: github-api

through the GitHub API, is it possible to get the number of open pull requests for a repository without downloading all the extra data related to the pull requests themselves?

For example, when you get the list of your repositories, for each of the repo you can see the number of open issues. Is there a similar property for open pull requests?

Comment: My first answer was wrong as the search api keywords only match the content of the issue and the test I did was against an issue that contained the word "pull" in its description. So there is no way to filter for pull requests only. 
I ended up just using the Pull Requests API for each repo for the moment:
http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests

not ideal as I just want to know the count of pull requests.

Comment: I would change the title: .."get count of open pull requests"... As for the total number of pull requests, with indeed an approximation, I used this: https://api.github.com/repos/ ... &state=all&page=1&per_page=1 . I mean I guess the english is ok (I am not EN speaker), but my search for total number of landed here ;)

Answer (score 8):

You might also take a look at the search api https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues. Looks like you can filter on type and probably also on closed or not :)

As suggested by [codea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832488/codea) in the comments:

```
https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=+type:pr+user:StackExchange&sort=created&order=asc
```

Comment: `https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=+type:pr+user:StackExchange&sort=created&order=asc`

Comment: how to overcome 30 hits limit? Is there a way to get each repo count in one for org in one hit.

I tried below query but it gives count for all repos:

        `https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=+type:pr+org:orgName`

Comment: @ShahidSiddique take a look at https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination

Answer (score 0):

I used the [Pulls Request API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls#list-pull-requests) in combination with jq ability to count objects (see [How to count items in JSON object using command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334348/how-to-count-items-in-json-object-using-command-line))

With cURL:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/pulls | jq length
```

With [Github CLI](https://cli.github.com/)

```
gh api \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  /repos/OWNER/REPO/pulls | jq length
```

Note:
The results are paginated. If you need more than 30 use the `per_page` query-parameter to increase the limit to 100. If you need more than 100 you need to implement paging, eg use the page query-parameter.

Comment: the results are paginated, this will show 30 at most

Comment: @AndreiC True, but you can set the page size up to 100. I guess for most use cases this is sufficient, not much repos have more than 100 open pull requests

Comment: sorry, not true, I tried getting the PRs and issues from webpack/webpack and there are tens of pages. You're also assuming I'd be querying the API just for open PRs.

Comment: @AndreiC it is true, check the docs and try it:
curl https://api.github.com/repos/webpack/webpack/pulls?per_page=100 | jq length
It displays 100 (because thats the limit per page). As I said there arent many repositories with more than 100 PR's and for that you implement paging. But for that you might need more than a single command.

The most voted solution have the same pagination "issue", I dont understand why you only comment on mine.

The question was how to querying for open PR, since your commenting on this, I assume you did.