# How to count items in JSON object using command line?

Tags: json, bash, curl, jq

I'm getting this kind of `JSON` reply from a `curl` command:

```
[
  {
    "cid": 49,
    "pyn": "yi4",
    "hans": "亿",
    "hant": "億",
    "tid": 68,
    "l10n": "cent million",
    "pid": 1,
    "pos": "num",
    "pos_txt": ""
  },
  {
    "cid": 50,
    "pyn": "yi4",
    "hans": "亿",
    "hant": "億",
    "tid": 69,
    "l10n": "100 millions",
    "pid": 1,
    "pos": "num",
    "pos_txt": ""
  }
]
```

How can I count the number of items in the array (here `2`), using `Bash` or a command line (e.g. `underscore`) ?

Comment: Is JavaScript solution, okay for you?

Comment: Through `NPM` module yes. Otherwise, no.

Comment: Check my solution. That needs no npm. Plain JavaScript.

Comment: I'm in a bash context, not web

Answer (score 676, accepted):

Just throwing another solution in the mix...

Try [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/), a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor:

```
jq length /tmp/test.json
```

Prints the length of the array of objects.

Comment: Your initial `jq` code (`.[]`) return the length of each `object` in the root array, while I'm looking for the length of the root array itself. Need to fix to `.`

Comment: If your root is not an array but an object with a key that contains an array, i.e. { "key": [elem1, elem2] } , then you can use use `jq '.[] | length' file.json`

Comment: Another useful option for that @MnemonicFlow is `jq map_values(length) file.json` . That will give you the keys as well.

Comment: And if your input is made of independent objects instead of a single array, you'd use the `-s` or `--slurp` option, which collects them into an array while reading: `jq -s length file.json`

Comment: `. | ` is not required, `jq 'length' ... ` is enough

Comment: @bitek Either I understood you wrong, or you're mistaken. `echo '{"key":[1,"asdf"]}' | jq '.[] | length'` gives an error. What produces expected result to me is `echo '{"key":[1,"asdf"]}' | jq '.key | length'`.

Comment: Bitek's method (`.[]`) works for me but it's just a shorthand for `.key`, usable when the object is only a wrapper around an array (in which case the key is basically arbitrary).

Answer (score 102):

You can also use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to track down the array within the returned json and then pipe that in to a *second* `jq` call to get its length. Suppose it was in a property called `records`, like `{"records":[...]}`.

```sh
$ curl https://my-source-of-json.com/list | jq -r '.records | length'
2
$
```

Answer (score 91):

The shortest expression is

```
curl 'http://…' | jq length
```

Answer (score 24):

If the `JSON` is being read from a file, try this -

```
number_of_objects=`jq '. | length' json_file_name.json`
echo $number_of_objects
```

If the `JSON` array is inside a key in the `JSON` as shown below -

```
{
  "fruits": [
    "apples",
    "oranges",
    "pears"
  ]
}
```

try this -

```
number_of_objects=`jq '.fruits | length' json_file_name.json`
echo $number_of_objects
```

(You'll have to download [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for this solution to work)

Answer (score 13):

Assume this structure:

(stored in a variable named `json`)

```
{
    "results": [
        { "id": 1 }
        { "id": 2 }
    ]

}
```

If you're looking to count how many are in the  `results` array, the command is:

```
$json | jq '.results | length'
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution is to install [`jshon`](http://kmkeen.com/jshon/) library :

```
jshon -l < /tmp/test.json
2
```

Answer (score 2):

try qic.  it works like jq/jello.  qic support interactive mode as well.

```bash
cat test.json | qic "len(_)"
```

https://walkerever.github.io/qic/