# Bash - Check if AWS CLI command output is empty

Tags: bash, amazon-ecr

I am running a command to filter docker images from my ECR repo.

`aws ecr list-images --repository-name {name} --filter "tagStatus=TAGGED" --query 'imageIds[?imageTag==`{some string}`]' --output json`

If no matches are found, the output is an empty array like so:

`[]`

If matches are found. the output looks something like this:

```
[
        {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:b2adff0....",
            "imageTag": "latest"
        }
]
```

**The goal is to figure out if the tag I am querying for exists in the output.**

I thought I could check check if the resulting array was empty by running `if [[ ${#IMAGES[0]} == 0 ]]; then` but both outputs have a length of 1.

I'm not a bash expert so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can pipe the output of the command into `jq` and perform validations and subqueries on the output. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334348/how-to-count-items-in-json-object-using-command-line. There is also a `length` check.

Comment: If `$IMAGES` just contains output string, you can do `if test "$IMAGES" = "[]"`

Answer (score 0):

Using `jq` to parse the json output you can create a bash array:

```sh
images=( $(aws ecr list-images --repository-name {name} --filter "tagStatus=TAGGED" --query 'imageIds[?imageTag=={some string}]' --output json | jq '.[].imageTag') )
printf 'number of images: %d\n' "${#images[@]}"
printf '%s\n' "${images[@]}"
```

Comment: Use `-r` to tell `jq` to output the raw values, not encoded as JSON.